# CSS designed unable create style and logo

Tags: jquery, html, css

Very roughly I created a CSS basic header design but I have issue that I unable to create [left side section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fs9Y0.jpg) as mention in image which shows in black color or unable to [add image icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5Vs7.jpg) in mobile version where red color represent.

I am new on stackoverflow please help someone. My code is mention below on which I work.

```js
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto"/>
```

```css
body {
 background-color: #233646;
 /* background: linear-gradient(to left, #23272D 220px, #23272D 1000px) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); */
 color: #5A5A5A;
 font-size: 13px;
 line-height: 1.5;
}
/*lists*/
ul {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}
li {
 list-style: none;
 display: block;
}
/*heading*/
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
 color: #555555;
 margin: 2px 0;
 padding: 2px 0;
}
h1 {
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 24px;
}
h2 {
 font-size: 22px;
 font-weight: 300;
}
h3 {
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 300;
}
h4 {
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 20px;
}
h5 {
 font-size: 13px;
 line-height: 18px;
}
h6 {
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 17px;
}
h-light {
 color: #949494;
}
p {
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}
a {
 color: #555555;
 cursor: pointer;
}
a:hover {
 color: #555555;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
 outline: 0;
}
.bold {
 font-weight: bold;
}
hr {
 margin: 15px 0px 10px 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 border-top: 0px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
 height: 0px;
}
.center {
 text-align: center;
}
a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
 outline: 0;
}
:focus {
 outline: none;
}

::-moz-focus-inner {
 border:0;
}
.mainbar {
 position: relative;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 width: auto;
 /*background:#eee url("../img/main-back.png") repeat;*/
 background-color: #fff;
 z-index: 50;
 min-height: 500px;
}
.mainbar .container {
 max-width: 100% !important;
 width: 100% !important;
}
.mainbar .page-head {
 background-color: #fff;
 padding: 0px 20px;
 border-bottom: solid 3.222px #012B72;
 height: 55px;
}
.mainbar .page-head h2 {
 color: #012B72;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 29px;
 padding-top: 11px;
}
.heading-menu {
 line-height: normal;
 height: 100%;
}
.heading-menu ul {
 height: 100%;
}
.heading-menu li {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 100%;
}
.heading-menu i {
 display: block;
 font-size: 16px;
}
.heading-menu a {
 background: none repeat scroll 0 center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 0;
 color: #012B72;
 display: block;
 font-size: 11px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 9px 8px 13px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 height: 100%;
}
.heading-menu a:hover, .heading-menu-active {
 background-color: #00B9F5 !important;
 border: medium none rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="mainbar">
    <div class="page-head">
  <h2 class="pull-left responsive-heading-title">Dashboard</h2>
  <!-- menu -->
  <div class="heading-menu pull-right responsive-heading-tabs">
    <ul>

      <li>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <a class="" href="#"> <i class="icon-folder-open"></i> <span>All Projects</span></a>
        </div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <a class="" href="#"> <i class="icon-folder-open"></i> <span>All Projects</span></a>
        </div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <a class="" href="#"> <i class="icon-folder-open"></i> <span>All Projects</span></a>
        </div>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
body message
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you want like this

```css
body {
 background-color: #233646;
 /* background: linear-gradient(to left, #23272D 220px, #23272D 1000px) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); */
 color: #5A5A5A;
 font-size: 13px;
 line-height: 1.5;
}
/*lists*/
ul {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}
li {
 list-style: none;
 display: block;
}
/*heading*/
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
 color: #555555;
 margin: 2px 0;
 padding: 2px 0;
}
h1 {
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 24px;
}
h2 {
 font-size: 22px;
 font-weight: 300;
}
h3 {
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 300;
}
h4 {
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 20px;
}
h5 {
 font-size: 13px;
 line-height: 18px;
}
h6 {
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 17px;
}
h-light {
 color: #949494;
}
p {
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}
a {
 color: #555555;
 cursor: pointer;
}
a:hover {
 color: #555555;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
 outline: 0;
}
.bold {
 font-weight: bold;
}
hr {
 margin: 15px 0px 10px 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 border-top: 0px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
 height: 0px;
}
.center {
 text-align: center;
}
a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
 outline: 0;
}
:focus {
 outline: none;
}

::-moz-focus-inner {
 border:0;
}
.mainbar {
 /*sition: relative;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 width: auto;
 background:#eee url("../img/main-back.png") repeat;
 z-index: 50;*/
  background-color: #fff;
 min-height: 500px;
}
.mainbar .container {
 max-width: 100% !important;
 width: 100% !important;
}
.mainbar .page-head {
 background-color: #fff;
 padding: 26px 20px;
 border-bottom: solid 3.222px #012B72;
}
.mainbar .page-head h2 {
 color: #012B72;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 29px;
 /*dding-top: 11px;*/
}
.heading-menu {
 line-height: normal;
 height: 100%;
}
.heading-menu ul {
 height: 100%;
}
.heading-menu li {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 100%;
}
.heading-menu i {
 display: block;
 font-size: 16px;
}
.heading-menu a {
 background: none repeat scroll 0 center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 0;
 color: #012B72;
 display: block;
 font-size: 11px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 9px 8px 13px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 height: 100%;
}
.heading-menu a:hover, .heading-menu-active {
 background-color: #00B9F5 !important;
 border: medium none rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
.pull-left {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto"/>
<body>
    <div class="mainbar">
    <div class="page-head">
    <div class="pull-left">
      <h2 class="responsive-heading-title">Dashboard</h2>
    </div>
  <!-- menu -->
  <div class="heading-menu responsive-heading-tabs">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <a class="" href="#"> <i class="icon-folder-open"></i> <span>All Projects</span></a>
        </div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <a class="" href="#"> <i class="icon-folder-open"></i> <span>All Projects</span></a>
        </div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <a class="" href="#"> <i class="icon-folder-open"></i> <span>All Projects</span></a>
        </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
body message
</body>
```

Comment: An explanation would be nice

Comment: Sorry, you code is totally wrong. It can be made vote down. But I never vote down. I want look like this: `https://i.stack.imgur.com/fs9Y0.jpg` please run my code and see there is I want add left side black section only. Please update your answer.